# What does ^= mean?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Using the ^= in this function, but I cannot seem to understand what it means?

````
    for integer in a {
        value ^= integer
    }

    
    return(value)```
````

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html Bitwise XOR operator or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2964513

Answer (score 2):

It means the same as `value = value ^ integer`.

The bitwise XOR (^) operator may be used to invert selected bits in a register (also called toggle or flip). Any bit may be toggled by XORing it with 1.